# Trying to make an efficient way to find all factors in python using for loops

Tags: python

I found this efficient code but because I am a beginner i am not too sure about the syntax so I tried to convert it using for loops. My code had no output.
Their code:

```
from functools import reduce

def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
            ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

My code:

```
factors = []

def factor(n):
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % i == 0:
             factors.append(i)
    for j in factors:
        factor_2 = int(n/j)
        factors.append(factor_2)
    print(factors)

factor(88)
```

Could someone please help me understand the first code and possibly show me what it would look like with for loops.

Answer (score 4):

In your second `for` loop, you iterate on `factors` and at the same time append a value in each loop, so your list keeps growing and you never reach the end, which makes your loop infinite.

There could be many ways to solve this, one is to generate the factors by pairs in the first loop. You can sort the list afterwards if you want them in order.

```
def factor(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            factors.append(n//i)
    factors.sort()
    print(factors)

factor(88)
# [1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 22, 44, 88]
```

Note that I put the `factors = []` line inside the body of the function. Otherwise, it would be global, and it wouldn't be reset between successive calls to the function.